# mempool web app on pruned node

Tags: pruning, websites, mempool.space

What would happen when running [mempool web app](https://github.com/mempool) on top a catched up pruned node and track back to old transactions no longer in persistent storage?

Would it behave buggy? If so, would be in scope not to be buggy? In other words, does this software require to be on a full node?

Don't have any pruned node at hand to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires `txindex=1` in *bitcoin.conf* so will not work with a pruned full node.

> Enable RPC and txindex in bitcoin.conf:
> rpcuser=mempool
> rpcpassword=mempool
> txindex=1

https://github.com/mempool/mempool#bitcoin-core-bitcoind

Answer (score 0):

Running the Mempool blockexplorer software requires a full node with a complete [transaction index](https://github.com/mempool/mempool/blob/master/production/README.md#bitcoin) as the data source. Operating a full node with `txindex=1` requires a complete copy of the blockchain and is therefore inherently incompatible with the pruning mode. It stands to reason that operating a Mempool instance will not be compatible with a pruned node in the future either.